# Should Repositories be Responsible for Saving Related Entities?

Tags: architecture

I'm trying to create repositories in my app. The problem is mainly with 2 entities:

- Workspace
- Member

a `Workspace` has many members, while a `Member` is only related to one Workspace (so a member exists only within a workspace).

Workspace has the functionality to add members and check if members exist:

```
class Workspace(private val members: HashSet<Member>) {
  fun addMember(memberId: MemberId, name: MemberName, email: Email): Member {
    // ...
  }

  fun hasMember(memberId: MemberId): Boolean {
    // ...
  }
}
```

What I am not really sure about is wether to have 2 separate repositories [WorkspaceRepository / MemberRepository], or should the WorkspaceRepository be responsible for saving and populating members in the workspace?

If there will be a MemberRepository, how will be able to use the functionality in the Workspace? what will prevent me from just moving the business logic outside of the Workspace?

And if WorkspaceRepository will be responsible for everything, isn't it a bit much loading all the members everytime I load a repository?

Thank you.

Comment: Which approach is most suitable for your particular application?

Comment: @RobertHarvey in this particular case I'm leaning towards saving/loading members separately with another repository, but there will be a lot of access control and rules for members in the workspace so I don't want to move all of this logic to application services as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am not sure about is whether to have two separated repositories [WorkspaceRepository / MemberRepository]

As usual, the answer is *depends*.

Ok, the relationship `Workspace` <- `Member` is enforced, programmatically, from `Workspace`, which acts like an aggregation root. That's fine. But where do `Members` come from? When or how are members created, edited and listed?

When we add members to workspaces, are we creating members anew? When we remove them from workspaces, are we removing `Member` from the data store too? Or are we removing the relationship `Workspace - member` instead? As *@Cacnode* points out, *what's the `Memeber` life cycle?*

You have to answer questions like these to figure out whether `MemberRepository` is required and its features.

> what will prevent me from just moving the business logic outside of the Workspace?

Nothing can prevent a developer from moving/copying a piece of code from component A to B. What you can do is guide the API<sup>1</sup> consumer by not allowing walkarounds. To this end, encapsulation is key.

> If there will be a MemberRepository, how will be able to use the functionality in the Workspace?

It doesn't. `MemberRepository` exists to manage `members` not `workspaces`. It knows nothing about workspaces<sup>2</sup>.

> or should the WorkspaceRepository be responsible for saving and populating members in the workspace?

Why not?

Repositories are abstractions (ideally, proposed by the core). Think about them as interfaces. The key, then, is in the implementation.

```java
public class WorkspaceDBRepository implements WorkspaceRepository {
  private Dao<Workspace> workspaceDao; //<--- implementation detail
  private Dao<Member> memberDao; //<--- implementation detail
}
public class MemberDBRepository implements MemberRepository {
  private Dao<Member> memberDao;//<--- implementation detail
}
```

Let's say we finally want the list of workspaces a `Member` belongs to. A *one-to-many* join that most of ORMs implement out of the box.

```java
public class MemberDBRepository implements MemberRepository {
  private Dao<Member> memberDao;//<--- implementation detail
  private ReadOnlyDao<Workspace> workspaceDao;//<--- implementation detail
  //...
  //...
  //no public method with Workspace on its signature. Ever.
}
```

These are only examples. Probably not the most elegant ones, but they illustrate my point about abstraction vs implementation details.

---

<sup>1: *A*pplication *Public *I*nterface</sup>

<sup>2: Unless you implement `Member.workspaces`. That's the kind of *walkaround* I was talking about.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this made things more clear for me.
To answer your questions:
1. Members are controlled from the Workspace, so to create/delete a member this is done from the workspace itself.
2. When a Member is removed from the workspace it's also removed from the datastore since Members cannot exist on their own.

Having those answers, do you have a recommended way on what to do in this scenario?

Comment: Also if I went with having a WorkspaceRepository only that's handling the Members as well, how can I know when to persist a new member, or which member to delete if the only method I have is `save(workspace)`?
Or should I expose also functions as `saveMember(member)` and `deleteMember(member)`?

Comment: You can declare these methods,  but you don't make them public. You know, the walkaround you don't want the API consumer to know or exploit. Or the alternative is, to remove all the members of the given workspace and repopulate the member list with those in the object. All in the same transaction. This way, you avoid comparing _what do I have in memory_ with _what do I have in DB_.

Comment: You will delete members one by one if you have something to do first, like solving foreign keys (e.g other tables pointing to Member table or other workspaces the member belongs to). If Member is pointed by other tables or workspaces, the best you can do is save these relationships in a dedicated table `WorkspaceMembers`. So when you delete members from workspaces, you delete entries of this table, leaving alone the table `Members` and not messing with FK.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question you should ask is: can a **Member** live outside a **Workspace**?

If a **Member** can exist outside a **Workspace**, then I would opt for separate repositories, and would **assign** a Member to a **Workspace**.

If a **Member** is tied to an individual **Workspace**, and cannot exist outside it, I would use the **WorkspaceRepository** to create it.

For example, let's imagine an organization app with two entities **Checklist**, and **ChecklistItem**. The existence of a **CheckListItem** alone doesn't make sense. It needs to belong to a **CheckList** to have any meaning.

On the other hand, let us consider an e-learning app, like Coursera, with the entities **Course**, and **Student**. Right now the **Student** can be enrolled in multiple **Course**s, but at some moment they might as well not have any enrollments. In this case, the **Student** can live without the existence of any **Course**s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get this separation and in my case the Member can't exist outside the Workspace. Can you give me example on how the repository should look like? is it going to have `save(workspace)` that's responsible also for saving the members? If so, how would I know which members are newly added to avoid calling the db with pre-existing data?